# Attempt to dereference a null object - get the value of a custom setting

Tags: apex, customsetting

I try to access the value of a custom setting : this custom setting contains only one field `Nombre__c`and the name of the custom setting is `Limit__c`.

In apex I try to get the field `Nombre__c` :

```
Limit__c limite = Limit__c.getInstance('limit');
Integer nb = integer.valueOf(limite.Nombre__c);
```

There is only one value in this custom setting, named "limit" with a value in the field `Nombre__c`.

When I run my code I got this error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object in the logs.

Comment: Try to add a debug log to check whether the value is there or not in `limite`.

Comment: put system.debug('****limite *****'+limite ); to check what value you get in it and check if Nombre__c field has value in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possibilities what could be wrong:

1. `Limit__c limite = Limit__c.getInstance('limit');`

May be `limite` variable is null as there was no custom setting record where name was 'limit'. If this is true syntax `limite.Nombre__c` will throw null pointer exception as you can not refer Nombre__c of null.
So put a debug like

```
System.debug('limite==='+limite);
```

2. In case point 1 above do not apply it may be the case value `limite.Nombre__c` is null It means there is a valid custom setting record with name as 'limit' but there is no value stored in `Nombre__c` field of that record.

   For this case try debugging

System.debug('limite.Nombre__c==='+limite.Nombre__c);

One of the above point will be true for your case.